# What is "??" operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recently I am working on an official project, where I see **??** operator, but I can not understand what is this thing and how it works. Can anyone describe me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 0):

It's the [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator. It returns the left-hand side of the operator if it is not nullish, and the right-hand side otherwise

Example:

```js
let a = undefined ?? 1 // returns 1
let b = 2 ?? 3 // returns 2
let c = 0 ?? 3 // returns 3
```

Comment: thank you so much MrMikimn for your valuable comment. I got the thing.